# python 3.4 to python 3.5 upgrade

Tags: python, raspbian

How do I upgrade from Python 3.4 to 3.5 or higher on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian?

I tried `sudo apt-get install python3.5` with the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.5
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.5'
```

- I have also tried 3.6 and 3.7, receiving the same results

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your system doesn't have any activated repositories which has python 3.5.

I found [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54365/how-to-download-and-install-python-3-5-in-raspbian/56632#56632) solution for installing any newer python version (even 3.7)